# How to export the results of ANOVA test to an Excel file

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to export the results of a one-way ANOVA test (output below) to an excel file. The data set is mtcars. If I store the results, what is a good approach to export the results to a file

```
 summary(mtcars)  
 results <- oneway.test(mpg ~ gear, 
          data = mtcars, 
          var.equal = TRUE)


 One-way analysis of means

 data:  mpg and gear
 F = 10.901, num df = 2, denom df = 29,
 p-value = 0.0002948
```

Comment: It's not exactly in tabular format, so what is your desired result? A single column table?  If you just want to save it for safekeeping, could you just export as an .rds file using `saveRDS`?

Comment: Are any of the answers so far helpful? I note that you have asked 11 questions but have not yet cast any votes or accepted any answers. Please consider supporting the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`broom::tidy()` will get you some of the way, generating a tibble that can be written to CSV:

```
library(broom)

results <- oneway.test(mpg ~ gear, 
                       data = mtcars, 
                       var.equal = TRUE)
results_df <- tidy(results)

results_df

# A tibble: 1 × 5
  num.df den.df statistic  p.value method                   
   <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>                    
1      2     29      10.9 0.000295 One-way analysis of means
```

But the output doesn't contain the names of the data or variables, so you could add those manually:

```
library(dplyr)

results_df <- tidy(results) %>% 
  mutate(data.name = results$data.name, 
         dataset = "mtcars")

results_df

# A tibble: 1 × 7
  num.df den.df statistic  p.value method                    data.name    dataset
   <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>                     <chr>        <chr>  
1      2     29      10.9 0.000295 One-way analysis of means mpg and gear mtcars
```

Then use base `write.csv`or `readr::write_csv` to write to a CSV file for import to Excel (don't bother writing direct to Excel format).

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to `tidy` the model into a tibble, and write that to an Excel file.

```r
library(broom)
library(writexl)

results <- oneway.test(mpg ~ gear,
                       data = mtcars,
                       var.equal = TRUE)

tidy(results)
#> Multiple parameters; naming those columns num.df, den.df
#> # A tibble: 1 × 5
#>   num.df den.df statistic  p.value method                   
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>                    
#> 1      2     29      10.9 0.000295 One-way analysis of means

write_xlsx(tidy(results), path = 'results.xlsx')
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>